# Item not invalidating after fingerprint change with biometryCurrentSet iOS

Tags: ios, swift, security-framework

I am trying to save a password in the keychain with biometryCurrentSet SecAccessControl flag set. Saving and reading work as expected except if I add or add or remove a fingerprint. It still returns the password, I am expecting an error, as the documentation states the item will be invalidated.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/secaccesscontrolcreateflags/2937192-biometrycurrentset

```
guard let accessControl = SecAccessControlCreateWithFlags(kCFAllocatorDefault, kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlockedThisDeviceOnly, SecAccessControlCreateFlags.biometryCurrentSet, nil) else {
        print("COULD NOT CREATE THE ACCESS CONTROL FLAGS!!!!!")

        return
    }

    guard let pword = password.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) else {
        print("COULD NOT CREATE THE PASSWORD DATA!!!!!")

        return
    }

    let query: [String : Any] = [kSecClass as String : kSecClassGenericPassword as String,
                                 kSecAttrService as String : service,
                                 kSecAttrAccount as String : username,
                                 kSecAttrAccessControl as String : accessControl,
                                 kSecUseOperationPrompt as String : "Authenticate with biometrics",
                                 kSecUseAuthenticationUI as String : kSecUseAuthenticationUIAllow as String,
                                 kSecValueData as String : pword]

    let status = SecItemAdd(query as CFDictionary, nil)
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem was in my SecItemUpdate query I was not including the access control flags.